# bootstrap-datepicker format issue

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker, metronic

I cannot for the life of me get the date to format... can someone help before I rage delete my 'fun' project? :)

`console.log(date)` is almost perfect, showing: `2018-06-28T23:00:00.000Z` whereas the `input` field value is updated to `value="Fri Jun 29 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (GMT Summer Time)"`.

I can't understand why `console.log(e.date)` would show one thing and `.val(e.date)` would show something completely different?

Any help would be appreciated, I've read 15 sites and tried dozens of different configs. Thank you.

```
$(function() {
    $('#next_review_date').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yy',
        weekStart: 1,
        startDate: '+1d',
        maxViewMode: 2,
        clearBtn: true,
        daysOfWeekHighlighted: "1,2,3,4,5",
        todayHighlight: true

    }).on('changeDate', function(e) {
        console.log(e.date);
        $('#selected_next_review_date').val(e.date);
    });

});

<div id="next_review_date"></div>
<input type="hidden" name="next_review_date" id="selected_next_review_date" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Its StackOverFlow intention. The date objects are converted to ISOString format during console.

StackOverFlow has overrided the console statement to show the contents to their console.

[image: Date passed normally to console]

Dates are converted to ISOString before printing them.

[image: ISO string conversion by SO]

```js
console.log(new Date());
console.log(new Date().toISOString());
```

In the above snippet, you can see that the first console statement has printed the date in ISO format as string by StackOverflow.

In the second, the date is already converted to string, so printed as it is.

You can see the difference with the double quotes.

If you just see the browser console, it would be clear that it is printed in the expected format.

Answer (score 0):

already available datepicker on metronic.
my example:

```
<div class="m-portlet__body">
    <form class="m-form m-form--fit m-form--label-align-right m-form--group-seperator-dashed">
        <div class="m-portlet__body">
            <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="m_datepicker_1" readonly="" placeholder="date" data-date-format="dd.mm.yyyy">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```